# One type argument expected. Use 'Success<*>' if you don't want to pass type arguments in Kotlin [Android]

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, retrofit

I am trying to write a wrapper class for handling retrofit responses. I am having a very weird error which I am trying to fix for couple of days.

**Networkresult.kt**

```
sealed class NetworkResult<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val message: String? = null
) {
    //    class Success<T>(data: T) : NetworkResult<T>(data = data)
    class Success<T>(data: T) : NetworkResult<T>(data = data)

    class Error<T>(errorMessage: String?) :
        NetworkResult<T>(message = errorMessage)

    class Loading<T> : NetworkResult<T>()
}
```

**Base Repository**

```
abstract class BaseRepository() {

    suspend fun <T> safeApiCall(apiToBeCalled: suspend () -> Response<T>): NetworkResult<T> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val response: Response<T> = apiToBeCalled()

                //Returns true if code() is in the range [200..300)
                if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                    Timber.i("Success")
                    NetworkResult.Success(data = response.body()!!)
                } else {
                    Timber.i("Failed, ${response.message()}")
                    //In case of error sends the api failure message
                    NetworkResult.Error(errorMessage = response.message())
                }
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                //Exception if something went wrong from server
                NetworkResult.Error(errorMessage = e.message ?: "Something went wrong")
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                //Exception if there is no internet
                NetworkResult.Error(
                    errorMessage = e.message ?: "No Internet Connection"
                )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                //Other exceptions
                NetworkResult.Error(errorMessage = e.message ?: "Something went wrong")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside my main repository I extend this base repository and make a call to the safeAPiCall method :

```
    suspend fun saveGame(gameSaveRequest: GameSaveRequest): NetworkResult<GameSaveSuccessResponse> {
        return safeApiCall { api.saveGame(gameSaveRequest) }
    }
```

Inside my viewmodel:

```
 private val _saveGame: MutableLiveData<NetworkResult<GameSaveSuccessResponse>> =
        MutableLiveData()
    val saveGame: LiveData<NetworkResult<GameSaveSuccessResponse>> get() = _saveGame

    fun saveGame(gameSaveRequest: GameSaveRequest) = viewModelScope.launch {
        _saveGame.value = NetworkResult.Loading()
        //posting data once it is loaded
        if (hasInternetConnection()) {
            repo.saveGame(gameSaveRequest).let {
                _saveGame.postValue(it)
               /* when (it) {
                    is NetworkResult.Success -> {
                        _saveGame.postValue(it)
                    }

                    is NetworkResult.Error -> {

                    }

                    else -> {

                    }
                }*/
            }
        }
    }
```

Here as you can see I am able to do :

```
when(it) {
NetworkResult.Success -> {}
NetworkResult.Error -> {}
```

but when I use the same response by observing the variable on my fragment I get this error

**Fragment**

```
    viewModel.saveGame.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
//                        Timber.d("Network Result : ${it is NetworkResult.Success}") //TODO: Check with this
//                        Timber.i("Data: ${it.data}, message: ${it.message}")
                        when (it) {
                            is NetworkResult.Success -> {}
                        }

                        if (it.data != null) {
                            binding.tvSave.text = "Saved"
                            binding.ivSave.setColorFilter(
                                ContextCompat.getColor(
                                    requireContext(),
                                    R.color.red
                                )
                            )
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "${it.message}")
                        }
                    }
```

**Error:**

```
One type argument expected. Use 'Success<*>' if you don't want to pass type arguments
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your sealed class is poorly designed and defeats the purpose of even using a sealed class. `data` is forced to be a nullable property, even though it is only used by Success and Success doesn't make it nullable. So you always have to deal with a nullable `data` even if it isn't nullable. Other improvements: Error and Loading don't even use the generic type, so you can make them universal using `<Nothing>` so you don't have to specify the type when using them. And you can use `out T` so the class is more versatile. Loading can be an `object` since it has no state

Comment: so you don't have to fool with creating instances of it. Example: https://pl.kotl.in/zavXwngV6

Comment: As for your question...I've run into that before. I don't know the exact conditions that cause it. It's some limitation of the compiler under specific conditions.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks will make those changes. I fixed that issue btw. Had two classes with same name but in different modules. Wrong imports at different places was causing it.